# Движение объектов в OpenGL

Tags: opengl

Рисуется координатная плоскость и куб, необходимо обеспечить перемещение куба. Но в данной ситуации перемещается как куб, так и координатная плоскость. Что нужно добавить?

```
#include <glut.h>

void Reshape(int w, int h);
void Display();
void ProcessNormalKeys(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
void ProcessSpecialKeys(int key, int x, int y);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutReshapeFunc(Reshape);
    glutDisplayFunc(Display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(ProcessNormalKeys);
    glutSpecialFunc(ProcessSpecialKeys);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
void Reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-1000, 1000, -1000, 1000);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
void Display()
{
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex2i(350, 550);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex2i(350, 150);
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2i(650, 150);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2i(650, 550);
    glEnd();
    
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex2i(-10000, 0);
    glVertex2i(10000, 0);
    glVertex2i(0, -10000);
    glVertex2i(0, 10000);
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
void ProcessNormalKeys(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    if (key == 27)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    if (key == 65)
    {
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glTranslated(80, 80, 0);
        Display();
    }
}
void ProcessSpecialKeys(int key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
    case GLUT_KEY_UP:
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glTranslated(0, 80, 0);
        Display();
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glTranslated(0, -80, 0);
        Display();
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glTranslated(-80, 0, 0);
        Display();
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glTranslated(80, 0, 0);
        Display();
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Хочу сказать о том, что для того, чтобы переместить объект вам нужно перерисовать его в другом месте. Другого способа, насколько я знаю, нет. Т.е. вам нужно изменить функцию Display().

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: спасибо бот, но я давно не работал с c++ и opengl, поэтому ничего не могу добавить

Comment: можешь поверить на слово